# Warning: "The inferred tsconfig file "..../frontend/tsconfig.json" appears to be "solution-style"..." when do npm install

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm migrating a project to angular 12 and following this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-upgrade-angular-packagesenable-ivy-compiler) i added the `"postinstall": "ngcc",` comand in the script section on my package.json like this:

```
 "scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"dev": "ng serve -c dev --watch=false",
"postinstall": "ngcc",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
```

},

when i do npm install it shows the following warning:

```
> Warning: The inferred tsconfig file "..frontend/tsconfig.json" appears to be "solution-style" since it contains no root files but does contain project references.
This is probably not wanted, since ngcc is unable to infer settings like "paths" mappings from such a file.
Perhaps you should have explicitly specified one of the referenced projects using the --tsconfig option. For example:

          ngcc ... --tsconfig "./src/tsconfig.app.json"
          ngcc ... --tsconfig "./src/tsconfig.spec.json"
          ngcc ... --tsconfig "./e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    
    Find out more about solution-style tsconfig at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-9/#solution-style-tsconfig.

If you did intend to use this file, then you can hide this warning by providing it explicitly:

  ngcc ... --tsconfig "tsconfig.json"
```

What is the best solution in this case?
Should i just hide the warning like the message suggests?
Thanks.